# jquery change() binding doesn't trigger on first change (ASP.NET Validation)

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a form with a number of different elements.  In the Ready function I'm binding the "change" for these like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#someControlID').change(nameOfHandlerFunction);
    .... (similar code for all controls)
}
```

It works as expected for drop-down lists, but for textboxes, textareas, and checkboxes, the handler function doesn't get called until the *second* time I change the value.  I've placed a debugger statement in the handler to double check. If I focus a textbox, modify text, and leave focus, I'll have to do that a second time to get the handler to run.  Any idea what might cause this behaviour?

Edit: this was observed in IE 8.

Thanks!

Comment: What browsers are you seeing this in? Can you put an example up on http://jsfiddle.net please?

Comment: Well, this fiddle works first time around : http://jsfiddle.net/tPzqf/ so it's probably something in your end. You should post your code here

Comment: Your example works fine in the browser I'm developing for (IE8).  jsfiddle is a very handy site! let me do some more digging in my code and see what i can figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET was the culprit.  I didn't mention it in my question because I didn't think it was relevant, but there you go.  The controls in question had associated ASP.NET Validator controls linked to them.  On examination, the control elements' "onchange" was set to a function called "ValidatorOnChange".  Somehow, invoking jQuery's "change()" on these controls was causing the undesirable behaviour described above.

I worked around the problem by using my own event handler - this is probably not an option for everybody but I had this function available in a loaded library so I used it and the page works now.

The new code looks like:

```
var el = document.getElementById('someControlId');
el.onchange = appendFunction(el.onchange, nameOfHandlerFunction);
```

Here's the method itself in case this helps anybody else.

```
function appendFunction(fn1, fn2) {
    var result;

    // if neither arguments are functions,  return an empty function.
    // if only one argument is a function, return that.
    if (typeof (fn1) !== 'function' && typeof (fn2) !== 'function') {
        result = function () { return; };
    }
    else if (typeof (fn1) === 'function' && typeof (fn2) !== 'function') {
        result = fn1;
    }
    else if (typeof (fn1) !== 'function' && typeof (fn2) === 'function') {
        result = fn2;
    }
    else {
        result = function () {
            fn1();
            fn2();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```